# Launching custom desktop from command line with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to learn Linux, especially the cli and I have customized my grub file and replaced "quiet splash" with "text".

This has given me the ability to launch Ubuntu into cli only mode. When I run the startx command it launches a blank/default desktop. Is it possible to launch the same desktop I would see if left the "quiet splash" value in place.

In other words can I launch the desktop complete with the sidebar, time, short cuts and other stuff?

Comment: Did you try `startx /usr/bin/gnome-session` ?

Comment: The `quiet` and `splash` kernel options do not affect the desktop environment. They only affect the system's behavior **during** the boot process, not after it.

Comment: Also, you could use a terminal inside your desktop to learn the CLI.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I just started with Linux only two days ago and think I was getting ahead of myself a bit. I think I need to learn the basics from the ground up before I worry too much about customization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead of startx in the command line.

```
# unity
```